# Comparing context variable with entity in IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

In watson conversation dialog I have created a condition; something like

```
if $stored_state == @states:(Florida) AND $preferred_joint == @joint:(KFC)
then some response
```

where `$stored_state` is a context variable, which was stored at a previous node from user input. Same goes for `$preferred_joint`. `@states` and `@joint` are just two entities with fuzzy matching.
But condition like this never works. I also tried to use `@states:(Florida)` entity after converting it to a context variable. But still doesn't work.

Now, what do I do wrong there? Is there any way to compare context variable with entity?

Comment: Isn't `@states:(Florida)` a predicate on its own?

Comment: yes, I believe it is. But I need to check `stored_state` in any later node,`@states:(Florida)` just one single case.

Comment: You want something like `if @states:(Florida) AND $stored_state==Florida ....`

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. Though, I found a workaround. `if $stored_state == 'Florida' AND $preferred_joint == 'KFC'`. Thanks for the tip. Still waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, you want to check if the entity that the user just said at the last input matches what you had stored in your context?

You can use an AND condition for this right?
@states: 'Florida' && $stored_state == 'Florida'

This is declaring that the user just said the state florida, and the stored context variable is also florida.