# Comparing dynamic context variable with entity in IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

does anyone know how to check if the context variable is the value of an entities in the condition?
For example, I have the user input saved as a context variable, and I have 50 states in a state entity. In the condition, how to check if the context variable is a valid state entity value?

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far? Also, what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[Comparing context variable with entity in IBM Watson Conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516000/comparing-context-variable-with-entity-in-ibm-watson-conversation) : This question is similar to yours.

However, I recommend you to handle this situation by using "slot" mechanism. Create a slot in your node. In this way, you can store your user input as a context variable and check the condition if it is matched with the desired entity value. Check the link below.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-tutorial-slots